# Node.JS-code to chart generation software

Tags: software-development, charts, uml, component-diagram, code-conversion

I'm looking for a tool which automatically generates [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) diagrams, specifically [Message Sequence charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_sequence_chart) and Class diagrams, from existing Node.JS code.

I've tried [code2flow](https://github.com/scottrogowski/code2flow) ([online version](http://code2flow.com/)) which is a step in the right direction but doesn't do quite enough. I'm especially looking for dataflow paths and class diagrams.

[image]

Should run under Linux or Windows. If it's good stuff it doesn't have to be cheap.